# Symfony: Swagger UI assets on 404 in production only

Tags: symfony, swagger-ui, api-platform.com

I am trying symfony with api platform, all was working well until I try it on production. I qm unable to diplqy correctly the swagger, assets were in 404. If I turn on the APP_DEBUG assets load normaly.

I have tryied an assets:install and a clear cache.
I am using traefik, but with symfony server it is the same issue.

Bellow screenshot are from local test but it is the same from my production server.

[image]

[image]

symfony 7.0.2
api-platform/core 3.2

Thanks.